# Why are apps suddenly wanting access to phone dialer?

Tags: update

Does anyone know why applications that I can think of no reason to need to use the phone dialer are saying it is one of their requirements?

The apps in question are currently:

- HERE Maps
- Bing News
- Bing Weather

and I have spotted this on the Store -> Updates -> Requires section.

Needless to say I have not updated them at this time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**tl;dr**

The updated apps probably now provide the ability to detect phone numbers in the content shown in the app and allow you to make a phone call (or get to the dialer) from within the app.

---

With the Windows Phone being constantly updated, so are the developer tools pertaining to the OS. As the OS is updated, apps can start making use of the newer features available in the developer API's.

The apps you list are all Microsoft and Nokia apps and it makes sense that these apps are first to take advantage of any new features.

From the [Windows Phone Dev Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394025%28v=vs.105%29.aspx):

> Use the phone call task to enable users to make a phone call from your application. The phone call task launches the Phone application and displays the phone number and display name that you specify. The phone call is not placed until the user presses the call button. By using Launchers, you help provide a consistent user experience throughout the Windows Phone platform.

Comment: not sure I would have ever discovered this on my own

Answer (score 4):

Much of the [advertising](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/afc8a30a-e21a-4f63-9756-c38ee326bf4b/idcapphonedialer-required-for-advertising-toolkit?forum=wpdevelop) within apps now require this capability. This is done so that tapping on an ad can cause the [phone dialer to be launched](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206936%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.tasks.phonecalltask%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), the only api that uses this capability is the phone dialer task, which still means a user has to press the dial button.